# Do Banners always slow down an app when they appear?

Tags: ios, ipad, notifications

I have an iPad 2 and I've noticed every time I receive a Banner style notification (the temporary pop in bar at the top of the screen) inside of a game app the game visibly stutters for half a second.

Is this just how banners always affect performance? If I disable banners for an app will that eliminate the speed hiccup or is this a problem with the behind-the-scenes notifications too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the current state of iOS. You'll notice that incoming calls and pop ups (the old style notification) also negatively affect the performance of current app.

Comment: Is this a new issue in iOS or have past versions done this too? I'm wondering if they might fix it or if it's an "always been this way" sort of situation...

Comment: @BenBrocka The new notification center is only there since iOS 5. With you, I do hope they will improve it in the future, but who's to say?

Comment: @BenBrocka as Gerry has said, the banner notifications were introduced in iOS 5, but I can assure you that calls and the previous notification pop ups (now called "Alerts") adversely affected the system even in prior iterations (iOS 3 and 4). It seems even the added horsepower of the A5 and 512 MB of RAM are not enough to offset those resource intensive operations.