# Is it possible to disable the game center completely and permanently in iOS 6?

Tags: ios, game-center

I am trying hard to avoid signing in to Game Center, but the interruptions and pop ups make this hard to do.

My impression is that after the third time I don't sign into Game Center, a pop-up asks if I want to disable game center. The text implies I want to be really sure as disabling GC means I'll lose so many wonderful features. It also tells me I can always enable it later in Settings. Each time I'm offered to opt out, I say yes intending to disable GC.

If this worked, I'd think it great, but the next time I launch a game, the now allegedly disabled and definitely signed-out-of Game Center (into which, by the way, I've never signed in) is back asking me to sign in.

What can I do to avoid this?

Comment: I am with you... it is totally annoying, as Game Center serves zero purposes for me, though I have given it a fair chance numerous times.  Pointless app for me, but I have to have it welcoming me, throwing up logins, etc...   I want it to stop and go away!

Comment: I would be tempted to make a throwaway account and sign in to turn off Game Center and remove it from all notifications and then sign out. I'm not sure the app is able to save preferences to the device and not to an account. It seems odd that you can't sign out completely...

Comment: Weird, I thought I remembered seeing it as one of the possible things you could disable via the Restrictions screen. Seems that I was mistaken...

Comment: I tried that too (disabling via Restrictions) and yet, amazingly, the sequence of behaviors (*formerly described, see orig. post before edits) above persisted.

Comment: *bmike*'s suggestion above (sign in and disable notifications, etc) is the path other people have (apparently successfully) followed: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4477936?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: I've signed in and at least am no longer bothered by "please sign in!" notifications, although the annoying ["Welcome back"](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/35629/how-can-i-disable-the-welcome-name-banner-notification-for-game-center) popup still appears. But this doesn't solve the problem for those with more patience / aversion to signing in, i.e. who won't cave as readily as I did....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm concluding the answer is no until someone proves otherwise.